# Shape of arrays on the left and right sides do not conform

Tags: fortran, fortran90

```
real*8, allocatable  :: psi(:,:), h(:,:)
integer              :: n
real*8               :: t, dt
complex*16           :: ci

write(*,*) ' number of grid points '
read(*,*) n
write(*,*) ' total time '
read(*,*) t
write(*,*) ' time step '
read(*,*) dt

ci = (0d0, 1d0)

allocate(psi(n,n), h(n,n))
do j = 0, t, dt
   psi(n,j) = psi(n,j) - ci * dt * h *psi(n,j)
end do
```

I am basically trying to propagation wave function in a bad way.. but this project told me to propagate like this. So n is a constant, h is a n by n array.

Why it keeps telling me that shape of array on left and right sides do not conform in the do loop? How can I improve it to make left and right equal?

Comment: Well, `psi` is `real`, `ci` is `complex`. Are you sure that that casting works the way you intend to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gfortran 5.2 emits a little more information in its error:

```
    psi(n,j) = psi(n,j) - ci * dt * h *psi(n,j)
   1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 2 in assignment at (1)
```

The LHS of your array is rank 0, as as `psi(n,j)` is a scalar.  On the RHS both instances of `psi(n,j)` are rank 0 scalars, but `h` is a rank 2 array.  You have:

```
scalar = scalar - scalar * scalar * rank 2 array * scalar
scalar = scalar - rank 2 array
scalar = rank 2 array
```

This is because scalars are promoted to arrays of the proper dimensions for the above operations so they act on all elements of `h`.  To make the ranks equal on both sides you'll need to select a single element of `h` or perform some other operation on it that reduces it to a scalar.

---

It is worth noting it isn't clear if your loop is correct.  Your value of 'n' is fixed at value of the array bounds the user input so your loop is only iterating one row of the array and depending on the choices of `d` and `dt` you will exceed array bounds if `t > n` and none of the row elements between the interval `dt` will be changed.  Seeing how few elements will be touched by your calculation gives me the idea that it isn't right.  Your initial value of `j` is also out of bounds for your arrays because fortran array indices begin at 1 unless the bounds are specifically stated.